# Data integrity with multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am looking for a way to have data integrity. Example:

```
create_table :accounts do |t|
end

create_table :areas do |t|
  t.belongs_to :account
end

create_table :desks do |t|
  t.belongs_to :area
  t.belongs_to :account
end
```

So an Account has many Areas and many Desks. A Desk may or may not be associated with an Area.

How do I make sure that a Desk that belongs to a given area, of one account, cannot possibly be associated with an area that belongs to a different account?

```
account1 = Account.create!
account2 = Account.create!

area1 = Area.create!(account: account1)
area2 = Area.create!(account: account2)

desk1 = Desk.create!(account: account1, area: area1)
# This next statement should fail, because area2 belongs to account2. So a desk in account 1 cannot be assigned to an area of account 2.
desk2 = Desk.create!(account: account1, area: area2)
```

I know I can write rails validations to check that, but I was wondering if I can leverage some PostgreSQL features here.

Comment: Are you looking for a unique index on `account_id` on the `desks` table? If I understand correctly your problem.

Comment: No, an account can have multiple areas. I am looking for a way to make sure that if there is an area (area 1) that belongs to one account (account 1) and then many desks belonging to account 1 and account 2, then only desks belonging to account 1 can be associated with areas belonging to that same account. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should add this info to the question, it is slightly unclear as it is, at least to me, I may just be having a brain freeze however...

Comment: Oks I edited the questions to reflect that.